# Android network_security_config: is there way to define more than one pins to the same domain with different expiration?

Tags: android, security, ssl, android-network-security-config

I want to use SSL pinning via network_security_config.

There is an idea to define several pins with different expiration dates to replace one to another without the app rebuild

I have a correct network_security_config.xml file like this:

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <pin-set expiration="2025-02-22">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</pin>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

i.e. both pins have the same expiration date as "2025-02-22"

What should I do to define another expiration date for yyyyyy-pin?

Due to the documentation *Duplicate domain names are not allowed* and *Multiple  elements are not allowed* too. Therefore I cannot define an another `<domain-config>` with the same domain or an another `<pin-set>` with different expiration.

Am I right there is no chance to use default network_security_config to solve the problem?

Comment: It will use any of the `pin`s, so assuming that example.com starts using certificate y before certificate x expires, the app will not experience any interruption. You should set the expiration date (if used) to the latest expiration date of all your pinned certs.

Comment: I'm not sure how the app will behave if it starts using xxxx-pin after its expiration date.

Comment: Provided example.com uses certificate xxx or certificate yyy then your app will behave exactly the same as if you hadn't pinned anything (including rejecting an expired certificate). The pinning only comes into effect if example.com starts using certificate zzz which is not pinned. Then your app will refuse to connect to example.com.